# Can a Succubus suppress the power and effect of her kiss?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

The description of the Succubus in 5th edition D&D (MM, p284) seems a bit contradictory. Under **Beautiful Corrupters**, it says

> Appearing in the guise of a humanoid who has previously appeared only
>   in the victim's dreams, the succubus or incubus seduces or befriends
>   its victim, indulging all its desires so that it performs evil acts of
>   its own free will.

However, under **Deadly Kiss** of a Succubus, we read that

> (...) the recipient of the fiend's kiss gains no satisfaction from it,
>   experiencing only pain and the profound emptiness that the fiend
>   imparts.

The stat block of the creature has a specific entry for the kissing action called **Draining Kiss**. (The Succubus does have the **Shapechanger** ability as well, but that does not disable Draining Kiss.)

So, maybe it's just me, but "indulging all its desires" likely covers a bit more than a first, and possibly last, likely lethal kiss -- a kiss which would, by killing its victim too soon, prevent the Succubus from achieving her purpose, that is, making the victim commit the three betrayals.

In light of the above, the question arises:

**Can the Succubus suppress the power and effect of her kiss?**

(Sure I know I'm free to make whatever of the creature as a DM. What I'm primarily interested in is whether the official rules or the official "fluff" resolve this apparent contradiction someplace else, whether I overlooked something somewhere.)

Answer (score 12):

The way it's described seems very straightforward, yet I'm unsure whether it's actually the intended behavior. As we're left to guesses, I'll list what I think the MM is trying to say:

- *Deadly Kiss* is a quality of the character. It's described as "The kiss of a Succubus or incubus is an echo of the emptiness that is the fiend's longing for a corrupted soul," which makes me believe it's unable to suppress this effect, being tied to its own nature.
- *Draining Kiss* is an action, which has to be used in the RPG context, and unless they're doing so, they will simply kiss the other character normally (though with the effects of Deadly Kiss applying).
  In the character narrative, a Succubus must choose to drain its victim's vitality, but they can kiss them without doing so.

I would also say that they might be unaware of the effects of Deadly Kiss, thinking to pleasure their victim, while giving their motives away in the process, or unintentionally killing the victim too early. They would, however, have to be aware of the effects of Draining Kiss in order for it to make any sense.

Indulging in a bit of story design, they would likely be furious about unintentionally killing someone they already had worked on for some time, becoming more relentless trying to get to their next victim, yet learn that they must use very specific methods and can't simply turn a human by physical pleasures alone.

They would possibly turn mad from not being able to fulfill their own desires eventually, becoming chaotic evil and using their abilities to cause pain and suffering, rather than strive for their original goal of obtaining someone's soul, and therefore becoming more of a mindless fiend than a calculating enemy.

The question remains how Deadly Kiss actually kills, if it's not by the same means as Draining Kiss. I would say (and this has no ground whatsoever, it's simply my guess, or how I would see it playing out well) that the pain caused by the kiss is inflicting damage proportional to the corruption caused by the Succubus (that the victim would be subconciously aware of).

This way, a Succubus interacts with low-level NPCs the same way it does with high-level heroes, in that it can't simply kill off any character, yet will be able to deliver a last fatal kiss to a successfully corrupted character, obtaining their soul no matter how powerful they are otherwise.

---

Also, the three betrayals are only listed as a tale's narration, while the rest of the paragraph about obtaining a victim's soul seems to be written more in a rules context (emphasis by me):

> **Beautiful Corrupters** (...) A mortal bequeaths its soul to the fiend not by formal pledge or contract. Instead, when a succubus or incubus has corrupted a creature completely - *some say by causing the victim to commit the three betrayals of thought, word, and deed* - the victim's soul belongs
>   to the fiend. (...)

This means, as far as I would interpret it, that the Succubus has to corrupt a creature, which will usually involve that creature committing several actions that could in total likely be described as "thought, word, and deed", but could be as simple as a creature being fundamentally determined to taking revenge on a character by killing them. The creature could be seen as corrupted from that point on. The "word" component seems especially redundant to me, as a good character eventually turning on their friend and killing them should be corrupted enough, even if they never spoke of it before.

Comment: "thought, word, and deed" are three _stages_ of betrayal, i.e. one cannot betray by word unless he did that by a thought. The word "stages" was omitted for clarity.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph: While I wasn't aware that it's an established phrase (thanks for the hint on this), it doesn't change my original point that it's mainly a descriptive addition, not one to derive game rules from. I also believe that betrayal by word before betraying in thought is very well possible, for example if a character is careless and babbles about another's secret. Of course it would be harder to corrupt someone into carelessness within the scope of D&D, but it's by no means impossible.

Answer (score 6):

**Draining Kiss** is an action available to the Succubus like Dash, Hide, Claw or Charm.

Just as it doesn't have to Dash every time it crosses the room it can give a "normal" kiss without it being a Draining one.

Comment: Thank you. Would it be worth discussing that "deadly kiss" is probably a dramatic title for that section of the fluff describing the Draining Kiss, not the name of a distinct move?

Comment: @SirTechSpec: My answer is going into the details of why I believe they're seperate things altogether, just tied to the same physical action of kissing (in the same way that you can move your foot to step or to kick). At no point does the MM suggest that Deadly Kiss is an action, though.

Answer (score 2):

According to deep DnD lore, a Succubus can suppress the life draining power of her kiss, in a manner of speaking. If a Succubus truly comes to love an individual, and that person feels the same way about the succubi, she will give him a kiss on his lips. There is no name for this kiss, and it is only mentioned in the Forgotten Realms book Lords of Darkness (AD&D 1st edition, 1988).

While this kiss does stop his heart, it does not kill him. And he soon turns into a True Blood Vampire. For True Blood Vampires are one of the few creatures succubi can have a normal healthy romantic relationship and reproduce with.

It's not officially canon in 5E, but it's never been outright rejected by Wizards of the Coast. Meaning that you can run it as canon in your games.